# Are all sound waves periodic waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics, fourier-transform

1. **I am wondering what type of different sound waves there exists?** 
   Are **all sound waves** periodic waves, is there other types?
2. What does it mean when we put the word **complex** before a wave, like complex periodic wave?

*I am new to physics and I've gotten confused about some terms and I would love it if someone could clarify them for me.*

Im very grateful for any answers/comments that can help! Thanks!

Comment: An example of a sound wave that *is not periodic* : a sonar pulse. Used by submarines as well as bats (ultrasonic) for echolocating, the sonar pulse is a *soliton* sound wave, an isolated disturbance in the sound medium with no periodicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function (a signal) is periodic in time when it repeats itself, when there is a period $T$ so that for all times $t$ it is valid that $f(t) = f(t + T).$

Only tones are periodic. For example a vowel has a period given by the movement of the vocal chords. Other sounds are not periodic: clicks, noise from waterfalls, the letter "s", etc. And even the sound from a bell is not really periodic: the frequencies do not have harmonic ratios. Same for a chord played on an instrument with equally tempered tuning.

"Complex" can mean different things. It may refer to the representation as complex functions like $e^{i\omega t}.$ Or it may be a wave that is not a sine function with just one frequency.

Comment: Can you please clarify or tell me more about "Only tones are periodic."

Comment: @HilulukAdde A tone has a pitch, a fundamental note with a certain frequency $f$. In general, the tone also contains harmonics (overtones) with frequencies $2f, 3f, ...,$ with amplitudes and phases that can be determined with Fourier integrals.

Comment: Im getting a better understanding but could you perhaps give me an example or two of periodic waves that arent tones? Like something from nature? Thank you I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @HilulukAdde There are no periodic waves that are not tones.